# Visible package folders in eclipse dart workspace

Tags: dart, dart-eclipse-plugin

I am using dart 1.9.00_dev with Eclipse luna. 
Everthing was working fine until I installed the package from this site https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_object
The package changed my whole workspace making all packages visible as 'raw' folders in the workspace. Before, only the highlighted package was present.

I removed the `.dartium` and the `pub` folders from my windows user directory and all packages from the projects and then performed `pub get` first then `pub upgrade`. But again the package folders are still visible. They fill my workspace and make it look quite unsightly.

How do I prevent these extra folders from being visible. Removing the offending `json_object`, removing `pub`, `.dartium` directory and all packages from my projects does not work.

Please see the attached graphic.[image]

**EDIT 1**

When I run pub cache repair command I consistently get the following

```
J:\dart\dart-sdk>pub cache repair
Downloading analyzer 0.22.4...
Downloading args 0.12.1...
Downloading barback 0.15.2+2...
Downloading browser 0.10.0+2...
Downloading bwu_datagrid 0.0.18...
Downloading bwu_emojione_iconset_svg 0.1.1...
Downloading bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg 0.0.8...
Downloading bwu_sparkline 0.0.7...
Downloading bwu_utils 0.0.2...
Downloading bwu_utils_browser 0.0.3...
Downloading clean_data 0.4.17...
Downloading code_transformers 0.2.3+1...
Downloading code_transformers 0.2.3+2...
Downloading collection 1.1.0...
Downloading constrain 0.2.0+1...
Downloading core_elements 0.3.2...
Downloading core_elements 0.4.0+6...
Downloading core_elements 0.5.0+2...
Downloading crypto 0.9.0...
Downloading csslib 0.11.0+2...
Downloading custom_element_apigen 0.1.3...
Downloading dev_string_converter 0.1.0...
Downloading dom_scheduler 0.0.1...
Downloading either 0.1.7...
Downloading event_commander 0.1.8+3...
Downloading firebase 0.2.1...
Downloading html5lib 0.12.0...
Downloading html_components 0.3.0...
Downloading http 0.11.1+1...
Downloading http_multi_server 1.3.0+1...
Downloading http_parser 0.0.2+5...
Downloading id 1.0.3...
Downloading intl 0.11.11...
Downloading jsonx 2.0.0...
Downloading liquid 0.2.1...
Downloading lists 0.0.20...
Downloading logging 0.9.2...
Downloading matcher 0.10.1+1...
Downloading matcher 0.11.3...
Downloading material_paper_colors 0.2.0...
Downloading observe 0.12.2...
Downloading option 0.3.3...
Downloading paper_elements 0.4.2...
Downloading paper_elements 0.5.0...
Downloading paper_elements 0.6.0+3...
Downloading path 1.3.0...
Downloading petitparser 1.3.2...
Downloading polymer 0.15.1+5...
Downloading polymer 0.15.3+2...
Downloading polymer_expressions 0.13.0+1...
Downloading pool 1.0.1...
Downloading quiver 0.18.2...
Downloading quiver_log 1.0.3...
Downloading scheduled_test 0.11.2+3...
Downloading shelf 0.5.6...
Downloading smoke 0.2.1+1...
Downloading source_maps 0.10.0+1...
Downloading source_span 1.0.2...
Downloading stack_trace 1.1.1...
Downloading string_scanner 0.1.2...
Downloading string_scanner 0.1.3...
Downloading template_binding 0.13.1...
Downloading template_binding 0.14.0...
Downloading unittest 0.11.1+1...
Downloading unittest 0.11.4...
Downloading utf 0.9.0+1...
Downloading vacuum_persistent 1.0.0...
Downloading validator 0.0.7...
Downloading vdom 0.7.1...
Downloading watcher 0.9.3...
Downloading web_components 0.9.0+1...
Downloading web_components 0.10.0...
Downloading yaml 2.1.0...
Downloading yaml 2.1.2...
Failed to repair bwu_emojione_iconset_svg 0.1.1. Error:
TimeoutException: Timed out after 30.0s while downloading https://pub.dartlang.o
rg/packages/bwu_emojione_iconset_svg/versions/0.1.1.tar.gz.
This is likely a transient error. Please try again later.
Failed to repair core_elements 0.5.0+2. Error:Reinstalled 72 packages.

TimeoutException: Timed out after 30.0s while downloading https://pub.dartlang.o
rg/packages/core_elements/versions/0.5.0+2.tar.gz.Failed to reinstall 2 packages
.
```

This is likely a transient error. Please try again later.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "installed the package"

Comment: As I have always done, I go to the pubsec.yaml Overview page, click 'Add', select 'json_object' and save the file. At this point all the folders start to appear.

Comment: I guess you have tried `pub cache repair`?

Comment: Yes, I did try that.

Comment: You didn't get any error message, when you did?

Comment: Please see EDIT 1 above.

Comment: It appears that pub is placing the folders in the cache directly in the workspace along with the symlinks.

Comment: It is after the analyzer is run that the folders are placed in the workspace.

Comment: I think you should delete the `AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache` folder and run `pub upgrade` again.

Comment: Did that numerous times with the same result. In addition I also deleted all packages folder in the project as well as the .dartium file in the user directory. I am now thinking that I might have to delete all projects, create them a new and take it from there. I will ping the author of the json_object package to see if he is aware of the issue - I must confess that the version of the package looked a little unmaintained. Thanks Gunter.

Comment: I don't think `json_object` is responsible. I guess this is caused by `pub`.

Comment: I have no doubt that you are correct Gunter. Maybe I am associating the start of the problem with the loading of the package json_object. Shall I wait on a resolution then form the pub team?

Comment: Have you reported the problem? You can try to start with a new workspace (rename the old folder) and just open the projects again.

Comment: I will do as you suggest.

Comment: Finally I get it to work again. I had to completely remove the eclipse ide and reinstalled everything.